# Change size of fragment, depending on text size?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 2 fragments inside a layout. In the first fragment I have a linear layout where textview text appears... - my problem is: when textview is too long it can't be read because the first fragment heigh is to short. is there any way to keep that system flexible?

i thought about to change fragment heigt due to textview length OR let a bar appear so i can scroll down (because at the moment i can't)... may you have other ideas or ways?

thank u

[image]

EDIT:
Fragment 1 contains as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bla"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:orientation="horizontal">

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25sp" />




    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this layout will be in fragment 1, in fragment 2 is some other fragment, does not play any role.
when text is getting to long it is not visible due to fragment 2 which overlap it

EDIT:

Solved it by "android:layout_height="wrap_content"  see comments

Comment: can you show your layout?

Comment: Multi-line `TextView` with a scrollbar perhaps?

Comment: Please post your code sample of layout

Comment: i postet an example... it's a simple layout where text is shown - but due to the fix size of fragment 1, the text is not fully shown when it is to long, due to its heigh, which is bigger than heigh than fragment 1

Comment: Please show your layout.xml
hint: set height of first fragment container to wrap-content

Comment: wrap_content did it! :) thx